# R and ggplot - plot distribution and line

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have a question that seems very simple, but I cannot seem to figure out. I have a dataset with treatments in a given year. There are 3 different treatments. I would like to create two plots:

One that looks like this:

[image: area plot]

And one that looks like this:

[image: scatter plot]

, except, I would like to stack multiple treatments (three instead of just the one in the example).

Let's say we have the follow df:

```
y=c(2001,2001,2001,2001,2002,2002,2002,2003,2003,2003,2003,2004,2004)
t=c("a","a","b","c","a","a","b","c","a","a","b","c","b")
df=data.frame(y,t)
```

I've tried using

```
geom_plot()
```

But it does not work. The closest I could get to have R do the proportions for me is the following stacked histogram using code from another post:

```
p+geom_histogram(aes(y=..density.., color=t , fill=t))
```

Comment: Can you complete your example? There are parts missing (like what is p?)

Comment: p would be the % of each t by year. in the df listed above, for 2001 there are 4 observations. p(a)2001 would be 0.5, p(b) = .25, p(c)= .25 etc. the p would be different every year. thanks.

Comment: But that's not how ggplot works. Ggplot doesn't do [data] + [geom].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the types of charts you show, you'll need to compute the proportions before you plot.  The `table` function can be used to do the counts of `t` by year and `t`.  `ave` with `sum` by `y` then computes the annual sums for the proportions.   Your first plot is made with `geom_area` while the second is a standard line and point plot.  The code could look like

```
library(ggplot2)
y=c(2001,2001,2001,2001,2002,2002,2002,2003,2003,2003,2003,2004,2004)
t=c("a","a","b","c","a","a","b","c","a","a","b","c","b")
df=data.frame(y, t)

# Count number of t's by year 
  df_tab <- as.data.frame(table(df), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
# convert counts to percents
  df <-  data.frame(df_tab, p=df_tab$Freq/ave(df_tab$Freq, df_tab$y, FUN=sum))
  df$y <- as.numeric(df$y)
# Set plot colors and themes
  plot_colours <- c(a="red3", b = "orange", c = "blue")
  plot_theme <- theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 18 )) +
                 theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 18)) +
                 theme(legend.position="top", legend.text=element_text(size=18))
# make area plot
  sp <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x=y, y= 100*p, fill=t)) + geom_area()
  sp <- sp + scale_fill_manual(values=plot_colours)
  sp <- sp + labs(x="Year", y = "Percentage of Patients")
  sp <- sp + plot_theme
  plot(sp)

# make line plot
  sp <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x=y, y=p, colour=t))
  sp <- sp + geom_line(aes(ymax=1), position="stack", size=1.05) + geom_point(aes(ymax=1), position="stack", size=4)
  sp <- sp + scale_colour_manual(values=plot_colours)
  sp <- sp + labs(x="Year", y = "Proportion Receiving Treatment")
  sp <- sp + plot_theme
  plot(sp)
```

which produces the plots
[image]

and

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for your help - it was super helpful and I was able to create the plots I needed. Just an update, I had to remove the `position="stack"` to create the line plot without summation of the proportions.